# closed form solution for the optimization problem

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, lasso

I have some what complex minimization problem, where the objective function is of the form,

$$
\lambda\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\|X_i\|_2 + \nu\|X\|_1 + \frac{\rho}{2}\|XP+Y\|^2_F
$$

In the above, $P$ is a double stochastic matrix, $m$ is the number of columns of $X$, and $X$ is a symmetric matrix.

I found many papers discussing soft thresholding strategy for a similar optimization problem with term $\|X-Y\|^2_F$ instead of $\|XP+Y\|^2_F$.  But introducing the double stochastic coefficient term complicates the derivation of soft-thresholding.  Is there a closed form soft-thresholding based operator to solve the above optimization problem ?

Comment: I'd guess not: this is like putting in a (doubly stochastic) design matrix into the group lasso, which is usually solved by iterative methods.